# TYPO3/TemplaVoila: Unknown column 'belayout' in 'field list' when adding new Template Object

Tags: typo3

We're trying to [implement a mobile version](http://www.dmitry-dulepov.com/2009/04/creating-mobile-version-of-web-site.html) of our Typo3 site, but whenever I  add a new Template Object and select something in "Make this a sub-template of", I get this error:

[image: typo3 error]

I'm not very good with typo3, so if anyone could point me in the right direction it would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Install Tool` > `Database Analyser` > `COMPARE` and mark the checkboxes to add missing fields and tables (you don't need to remove suggested things)

Repeat the operation as long as required, if some field can not be added by COMPARE, you need to include it manually via phpMyAdmin. Most probably in such case you'll need to resolve some conflict.

Next go to Extension Manager, find the `TemplaVoila` ext and search for `Update` button, to make sure that the config is saved correctly to the file.